# Quick launch does not select the correct active page when using querystring in url

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2007, quick-launch

I have a problem with the quick launch menu, it doesnot shows the correct active page when using querystrings in the urls.

Lets assume I have the following urls in quicklaunch items:

1. `/default.aspx`
2. `/default.aspx?ID=1`
3. `/default.aspx?ID=2`
4. `/default.aspx?ID=3`

For every visited link (item 1-4), item 1 is shown as active.

Is there an OOTB solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it with client script (needs jquery). Better solutions are welcome.

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
    $(".ms-selectednav").removeClass("ms-selectednav");
    var query = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop() + location.search
    var link = $("a[href*='" + query + "']:first");
    var table = $(link).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    link.addClass("ms-selectednav");
    table.addClass("ms-selectednav");                       
});
```

Comment: This seems to not work for me, since the class "ms-selectednav" is applied on page Title and not left navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that works on office 365. Just add to a script editor webpart. Not tested so much yet but seems to work for me.

```
    function fixLeftNavSelection() {
        var leftNavBar = document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar");
        var selectednav = leftNavBar.getElementsByClassName("ms-core-listMenu-selected")[0];
        if (selectednav !== undefined) {
            selectednav.className = selectednav.className.replace(/\bms-core-listMenu-selected\b/, '');
        }
        var query = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop() + location.search
        var navElements = leftNavBar.getElementsByClassName("ms-core-listMenu-item");
        for (var i = 0; i &lt; navElements.length; i++) {
            if (navElements[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf(query) != -1) {
                navElements[i].className = navElements[i].className + " ms-core-listMenu-selected";
                break;
            }
        }

    }
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("fixLeftNavSelection");
```